# VTable and Polymorphism

Tags: c++, inheritance, vtable

After reading alot about VTables, I still have one unanswered question.

Given the next class:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape {
public:
    int* a;
    Shape(){
        cout<<"default Shape ctor"<<endl;
        a = new int(15); // default
    }
    Shape(int n){
        a = new int(n);
          cout<<"Shape(n) constructor"<<endl;
    }
    // copy constructor
    Shape(const Shape& s){
        cout<<"copy constructor"<<endl;
        a = new int(*(s.a));
    }
    Shape& operator=(const Shape& s){
        cout<<"operator="<<endl;

        if (&s == (this))
            return (*this);
//      this.clear();
        a = new int(*(s.a));

        return (*this);
    }


      virtual void draw(){
             cout<<"print Shape the number is "<<*a<<endl;
      };
      virtual ~Shape(){
          delete a;
          cout<<"Shape distructor"<<endl;
      }
};

class Circle : public Shape {
public:
    int b;
  Circle() {
      cout<<"Circle constructor"<<endl;
      b=5;
  }
  virtual void draw() {
      cout<<"print Circle. The number is "<<b<<endl;
  }
   ~Circle(){
      cout<<"Circle distructor"<<endl;
    }
};
```

and the following test:

```
static void test2(){
    Circle* c = new Circle();
    cout<<"size of *c is "<<sizeof(*c)<<endl;
    Shape* s = c;
    cout<<"size of *s is "<<sizeof(*s)<<endl;
    s->draw();
}
```

I get this output:

```
default Shape ctor
Circle constructor
size of *c is 12
size of *s is 8
print Circle. The number is 5
```

My question is: I know how s addresses Circle::draw, but how can s know the variable b=5?
As this test show, s doesn't have this information. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

OK guys. Thanks for your quick answers...

I've learned from your answers that in Circle::draw() (*this) is of type Circle. OK. 
My question now has changed to this: Because I only wanted *s* to be a Shape* type, that is, I needed in my program only the Shape qualities. Is it possible that the next 4 bytes (the *b* variable in Circle) will be taken by the compiler somehow? If so, obviously Circle::draw() will not work as expected..

If not, how does the compiler knows that I will need these next 4 bytes after the "end" of s ?

Comment: Subtle bug: ~Shape does `delete a;` but you need `delete[] a`.

Comment: @pmr: That's wrong. `a` is allocated with `a = new int(15);`.

Comment: @Xeo: You are right. `new int(15)` vs `new int[15]` got me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing is that `s` points to a `Circle` -- and the `Circle` contains a data member called `b`. When `s->draw();` is called, the compiler calls `Circle::draw()`, as you recognise, and within `Circle::draw()`, the type of `*this` (i.e. the current object) is `Circle` not `Shape`. So `Circle::draw()` has access to `b`.

EDIT: In answer to your new question, `s` is a *pointer* to a `Shape` -- all you're doing is storing the same address (to the start of the `Circle` object in memory) but with a different type (`Shape*` instead of `Circle*`). The underlying `Circle` object exists in memory regardless of the things pointing to it. You can't access `Circle`-specific data members through `s` directly because it's a `Shape*`, but the virtual dispatch mechanism means that when you call virtual member functions through `s`, the call gets forwarded to the appropriate member functions in `Circle`, i.e. `s->draw();` actually ends up invoking `Circle::draw`. There's no danger that as a result of storing the address of the underlying `Circle` object in a `Shape*`, the underlying `Circle` object will be somehow 'sliced', getting rid of the `b` data member. Slicing only occurs when you do this sort of thing:

```
Circle c;
Shape s = c; // copies the Shape data members across from c, but slices off the rest
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `sizeof` tends to be a compile-time thing.  It's not looking at the object pointed to by `s`; it's just seeing that `s` points to `Shape`s and giving you the size of a `Shape`.  The information's still there; the compiler just isn't showing it to you because it's not keeping track of the fact that `s` points to a `Circle`.  You'd have to cast `*s` back to `Circle` to get the right size here -- but that'd be the same thing as saying `sizeof(Circle)`, which i'd imagine defeats the intended purpose.
2. `s` doesn't know anything except that it points to a Shape, and how to call `Shape` methods.  Since `draw` is a method on `Shape`, it can be called -- but since it's a *virtual* method, the object has a lookup table that says something like "for `draw()`, call here". For a `Circle*`, that table points to `Circle::draw` -- so the subclass's method gets called.  And since the pointer actually points to a `Circle`, there's a `b` after the rest of the `Shape` fields (that only `Circle` and its subclasses even know exists).

Answer (score 0):

As you say, s **points** to instance Circle and not just the draw method of instance of Circle. Therefore the methods in Circle have access to the instance variables of Circle. So when Circle::draw is called, it can "see" the instance variables as it is a member of Circle

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof()` gives the size of the type of the parameter passed. In this case type of `*s` is `Shape` class. But `s` is pointing to an instance of `Circle` class which naturally has an access to its overriden `draw()` method which prints the value of `b` which is also a member of `Circle`. As a part of the question's title, this is polymorphism and `sizeof()` has nothing to do with polymorphism.

This is also true for `typeid()` function, works with the type of the parameter, not the value of parameter or the object, parameter is pointed to.